# Beer Kegs and Deposits

Tags: acumatica

I need to bundle a stock item, 'Beer Keg' with a non stock item 'Keg Deposit'.

When a sales order is raised a beer keg is added to the sales order, a keg deposit needs to added automatically and the quality of keg deposits must be the same as the amount of beer kegs added to the sales order.

If a beer keg is out of stock, the keg deposit must not be invoiced.

Any idea how I can set this up? I have looked into Kit Items.. Is this the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The kit items will provide a way to get the total cost, but it will not show the items as separate lines on the SO or Invoice.  This could be confusing to the customer when he receives the invoice.

Last year at the Acumatica Hackathon, my team put together a customization of the Sales Order screen that handles "Related items".  Basically when a certain item# is ordered, an additional, related item is added as another line item to the screen.  I think this model will be better suited for your needs.

You can find the code on Github here:   https://github.com/simon-menard-lariviere/AcumaticaHackathon-TeamZeta

This should at least give you a place to start.